# "Deterministic" or real time like application programming on .NET

Tags: c#, timer, real-time

I have developed a .NET program for a SCADA solution to control a heavy machine but I have some problem related with time management on the application and I am looking for some wise advisory.

I use a Winforms timer to check regularly and record the values of some variables related with the process being controlled. The application spends about 40h turned on without interruptions. At the beggining the timer does it's job, at a 5 minutes time interval, it records the values to the database. But at the end of the 40 hours, the same timer without changing it's configuration is invoked only 1 time per hour.

So my question basically is "What's the best way to ensure a certain code is run on fixed periodic intervals in a program developed in C#?" I don't really need a pure real time solution, just ensure a function is called always in fixed time intervals. But those intervals are not quite critical, we are talking about 5 minutes length. Is not important how long it takes to run the code but it is important that the code is always executed on the same period of time.

Is it better option to run the application as a service rather than a regular user-space program? Is it better option to develop in C++ the "time critical" part and communicate with the C# code via sockets or so?

Comment: You might want to re-word your title and revise your `tags` to spare yourself the wrath of the _real-time_ crowd.  5 minute intervals is hardly _real-time_ programming

Comment: Without seeing the code it's impossible to say what's wrong but WinForms timers are not the problem. They will tick properly even after months so the problem is elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

> At the beggining the timer does it's job, at a 5 minutes time interval...
>
> I don't really need a pure real time solution...

*Windows Task Scheduler* is built for this in mind.  With it you can simply have it run an .exe of your choosing with optional arguments.  If the schedules are static you are arguably better off setting up the schedule in the TS UI or if complex, via the COM API.

Much better than having a another process hanging about counting down when TS already does it.